# How do I make a text go away when a task is completed in HTML?

Tags: html, text, locking, var, disable

Ever since I figured the `disabled` boolean, I wanted to show a text that indicates that you should complete a task before clicking on the button:

`<button type="button" disabled>Example</button>`
`<p> Please fill/check the boxes or optional text to click "Example".</p>`

And when the task is completed, that the text should disappear. This the one of the tasks:

`<textarea required>`

I will  fit all of this into a `<form>`.

---

#### Accepted Answer

The code for disappearing the text when task is completed, code for unlocking button, and explanation or snippet (without button) on how it would look like. Attributes I didn't use or different coding languages I missed should be included.

---

I tried using `<script>` and the `var` attribute to label the disappearing, but it ended up staying in place when I completed the required task. Is `disabled` the best boolean attribute for this?

---

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use some library or framework because that's a great example of statement management. You have to automatically render your content when your state is gonna change.

**Solution in React:**

```js
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('')
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(true)

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value)
    if (setText) {
      setActive(false)
    } else {
      setActive(true)
    }
  }
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setText('')
    setActive(true)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleOnChange} value={text} />
        <input type="submit" disabled={active} value="Example" />
      </form>
      {active ? <p>Please fill/check the boxes or optional text to click 'Example'.</p> : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using the js event system.

```js
//We write a function to test the conditions and set the disabled flag
//Now we only need to call this function every time the form changes
//Using addEventListner we can catch every "input" event and run the function
function check_task() {
  var text1 = document.getElementById("name1");
  var check1 = document.getElementById("check1");

  var problem_text = document.getElementById("problem");
  var button1 = document.getElementById("b1");

  var done_everything = true;                     //assuming everything is correct.
                                                  //setting done to false if something 
                                                  //is not correct

  if (text1.value == "") done_everything = false;//Condition 1: text1 is not empty
  if (!check1.checked) done_everything = false;  //Condition 2: check1 is checked

  if (done_everything) {
    button1.removeAttribute("disabled");         //remove the disabled tag
    problem.style.display = "none";              //hide the promt
  } else {
    button1.setAttribute("disabled", "");        //add the disabled tag
    problem.style.display = "block";             //show the promt
  }
}

var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");  //reference to the form
form1.addEventListener("input", check_task);   //add the event listener
```

```css
input {
  margin-top: 1%;
}

#check1 {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <label for="name">Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="name1" required/><br>
  <label for="check1">Newsletter: </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" required />
  <p id="problem"> Please fill/check the boxes or optional text to click "Example"</p>
  <p>
    <input id="b1" type="button" value="Example" disabled>

</form>
```